# Does Web Browser Task in Windows Phone support jquery-ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, windows-phone-7, inappbrowser

I am building a hybrid application for iOS , Android and WP7. The application simply implements push notifications and opens an in-app browser where i run some jquery.

The jquery makes some ajax calls that work fine on the iOS and Android platform.

In the WP7 platform i use the Web Browser Task to open an in-app browser but the ajax calls are never made. However when i try from the browser of the phone , everything works fine. Does the Web Browser Task not support ajax calls?

Are they by default , disabled and i should enable them in my code? Cause in android i remember, i had to enable the javascript in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have set the property [`IsScriptEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of your `WebBrowser` control to True.

Comment: Yeap exactly what i needed! Now works great! Just one more question if you happen to know. The html page that i load looks very very small and i have to zoom in to see it. Do you know why? On the iOS/Android looks ok , takes full screen. Here is unbelieavably small. And 2nd i am using a javascript alert function but it doesnt work in the in-app browser even with ur suggestion(in the device browser it works). Any ideas

Comment: If you can edit the page's HTML, you may be able to set the viewport to render at the correct size. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/22/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7.aspx